# Excel VBA Delete Duplicate Rows

Tags: vba, excel

I have an issue that seems so simple it is ridiculous but the duplicates are not deleting.  I have the below code which should reference one row versus another and if all is the same between the rows I want the duplicates deleted.  It isn't that the code errors out, it just doesn't delete the rows.

```
With Sheets("PR0Perf")
    lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    Set rng = Range("A1:T" & lastrow)
    rng.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13 _
    , 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19), Header:=xlYes
End With
```

It'as as if it is failing to highlight all of the cells on the sheet.  Does anyone have any idea what the issue could be?  I could paste the whole script but it is pages long.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you are trying to remove the duplicates from the worksheet named "PR0Perf", and not from the `ActiveSheet`, qualify your `Range`, `Cells` and `Rows` objects:

```
With Sheets("PR0Perf")
    lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    Set rng = .Range("A1:T" & lastrow)
    rng.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13 _
    , 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19), Header:=xlYes
End With
```

---

Note:  The code is only checking for duplicates in columns A:S. This means the value in column T will be the one applicable to the first row found for each unique combination in A:S.

Comment: You are correct I am trying to remove all duplicates from the worksheet PR0Perf.  I am not sure I fully understand what you are saying when you say qualify the range, cells and row objects.  The number of rows happens to be dynamic each time the macro runs which is why I am using lastrow.  Maybe I am over-complicating this and I could just run a macro to remove all duplicates from the entire sheet.  Is that even possible?

Comment: Turns out I am an idiot and was trying to remove duplicates on a filtered sheet.  Once I did an if then to remove that filter it now works perfectly.

Comment: @GregHerr Qualifying the `Range`, etc, references is referring to the fact that (for example) `Range("A1:T" & lastrow)` is interpreted as `ActiveSheet.Range("A1:T" & lastrow)`, i.e. it works on whichever sheet is active at the time.  If you want to specifically do something to the "PR0Perf" sheet, you should use `Sheets("PR0Perf").Range("A1:T" & lastrow)`, so that's the difference between the code in my answer and in the question.  (And I make use of the fact that you have a `With Sheets("PR0Perf")` block which allows me to use the `.` shortcut instead of `Sheets("PR0Perf").` several times.)

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to remove duplicates from a sheet that had a filter.  Once I set the Macro to remove the filter prior to running the above code my problem went away.  Thanks for the feedback team!